# What does id mean in this context?

Tags: google-apps-script, user-agent

I am having hard time to figure out what does id mean in this context.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: )
```

Comment: Maybe it's script id. Or just some type of id to identify the request is made from this Google account. Google doesn't  document it.